# From header php mail() send sms to phone number

Tags: php, email, sms

I really want to change the from parameter to absolutely anything I want, when sending sms with php's `mail()` function.
e.g the user sees `text message from "the developer"` on their phone screen.
I don't want the `@domain` From response, nor the email address.

```
$headers = "From: " . "the developer" . "\r\n";
mail('#@domain', 'check', $client, $headers);`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I have seen, headers are stripped / replaced by the SMS gateway with headers they prepare. So altering the FROM parameter on your end will have no effect. The only option would be to look at renting a short code number or using a price-based SMS gateway provider. I'm assuming this measure is in effect to prevent malicious intent.

Comment: It strips the headers but READS the headers to figure out what the "from" is going to say.

Comment: so that is the only option? really? how much could that be?

Comment: i wanted to do all that without involving anyone else!

Comment: isn't there a way to bypass the "header stripping"?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a -f flag to mail in order to override the sender, but I warn you that doing so will cause an `X-Authentication-Warning: hostname: www-data set sender to info@example.com using -f` header on the receiving end unless this host is allowed in your `/etc/mail/trusted-users` which you may not have control of if you're on shared hosting.

Comment: do you mean something like this: $headers = "From: " . "the developer" . "\r\n";
mail('#@domain', 'check', $client, $headers, '-fthedeveloper');